# Input box, Find and select entire column

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a small project for my department and i got stuck on a piece of vba code that i cannot figure out.

I am trying to use input box and find in the same code to search for a date within a selected range. After the date has been found i would like the code to select the entire column plus the next 7 after that and copy to a different workbook.
I can work out the code to transfer the copied data i just cannot get past find and select.

I always get the error "Run-time error 91, Object variable or with block variable not set".

The code is as follows:

```
Dim iDate As String
iDate = Application.InputBox("Insert Last Sundays Date")

rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Find(What:=iDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Any help in this matter i would greatly apreciate it.

Thank you.

EDIT: I have manage to find out why i was getting that error, my Dim was wrong i have now put it as Date rather than string. However i cannot figure out the selection part.

EDIT#2:

[image: Data from Excel]

(Picture is cut down due to privacy.)

Update on Code:

```
Dim iDate As Date
Dim eDate As Object
rows("1:1").Select

iDate = Application.InputBox("Insert Last Sunday's Date")

Selection.Find(What:=iDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Set eDate = ActiveCell

eDate.EntireColumn.Select
```

Comment: Nitpick: `"Insert Last Sundays Date"` should be `"Insert Last Sunday's Date"`. It will make the end-result seem slightly less professional if it has a minor typo.

Comment: By the way, your code works for me. Perhaps it is a date formatting issue. You think something in your spreadsheet is 5/11/2016 (November 5th in some regions)  but VBA thinks it is May 11th. Something along those lines. It would help if you edit your question to give a mock up of row 1 data, including a cell which you think should be activated but isn't (along with the value that you enter in the input box).

Comment: John, thank you for your reply, the text is just a mere example of how it should be looking, non the less i have managed to make it work for the selection of the cell that contains the date i am looking for and also to select the entire column of the active cell. Now i cannot make the selection for the 7 columns i need. I will add a picture of the data i am using within the main question. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least part of the problem is that you are (in the case of not finding the date) trying to activate `Nothing`, which isn't possible. That was what was behind the original error message ("Run-time error 91, Object variable or with block variable not set".) To guard against this, do something like:

```
Sub test()

    Dim iDate As Date
    Dim R As Range

    iDate = Application.InputBox("Insert Last Sunday's Date")
    Rows("1:1").Select

    Set R = Selection.Find(What:=iDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not R Is Nothing Then R.Activate

End Sub
```

Your comments suggest that you have still other issues, but this will address one potential problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help provided.

Comment: i figured out the other problem of the code: To select my additional columns i have used this expression: Selection.Resize(Selection.rows.Count + 0, Selection.Columns.Count + 7).Select